# Cluster points in a non-convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and write $n = 2^{j-1}(2k-1)$ for $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$. Define the sequence $(S_n)$ as

$$
S_n = 1/j+1/k.
$$

Find all the cluster points of $S_n$ and evaluate the limit superior and inferior.

If $n$ is odd, then $k=(n+1)/2$ and $S_n = (n+3)/(n+1)$. This implies that $1$ is a cluster point. When $j=k$, $S_n = 2/j$ and $0$ is another cluster point. One can also has cluster points for which $j$ (or $k$) is finite and fixed and $k$ (or $j$) can be arbitrary large. Then all the rational numbers of the form $1/j$ with $j$ finite are cluster points. From the above $\limsup S_n = 1$ and $\liminf S_n=0$.

Did I missed cluster points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found all of the cluster points. Suppose that $x\in(0,1)\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$; then there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1{n+1}<x<\frac1n$. Let $\epsilon=\frac12\left(x-\frac1{n+1}\right)$. Then $\left|x-\left(\frac1j+\frac1k\right)\right|<\epsilon$ for all $j\in\Bbb Z^+$ and all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $k>\frac1\epsilon$, so $x$ is not a cluster point of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(1/j_m+1/k_m)_{m\in \Bbb N}$ converge to $x.$

There is an infinite $S\subset \Bbb N$ such that $(1/j_m)_{m\in S}$ converges to some $y.$ And either $y=0$ or $y=1/j$ for some $j\in \Bbb N.$  (In the latter case we have $1/j_m=1/j$ for all but finitely many $m\in S.$)

And there is an infinite $T\subset S$ such that $(1/k_m)_{m\in T}$ converges to some $z$ with either $z=0$ or $z=1/k$ for some $k\in \Bbb N.$

So $(1/j_m+1/k_m)_{m\in T}$ converges to $x=y+z.$

So you did not miss any cluster points.